# 2009 Ford Ranger heater Blend Door

Tags: ford, ac, hvac, ranger

My heat blend door actuator burned out.  I bought a new one. I installed it but the blend door only moved a fraction of what it is supposed to so I disconnect the actuator to not burn it.  My question is;  It seems that it might be something that is preventing the blend door from working properly but I don't know what it could be.  I am suspecting that the door can either be damaged or there is a foreign object that is preventing it from moving properly.

Do any of you how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

That's a classic Ford problem.  I doubt it's an *object*, but perhaps dirt, leaves, or deteriorating foam surround door seals.  Try and twist the fluted knob with the actuator off.  If the blend door resists, you are going to have to isolate the restriction in travel.  People have soaked the area with WD-40 or similar with some success, but I don't recommend that as it just attracts more grit later.

Comment: Thanks Steve. I already tried to rotate the blend door by using the shaft of the old activator. I guess I will have to open the unit by cutting an access door from the bottom and see what is in there. I will get back to you when done but it may take me a while.

Comment: google that and you'll find a template that shows where and how to cut that access door without damaging anything  (other than the gaping case hole).  I did it a lot on Explorers of that vintage.  Pain in the rear, but you are not alone.